# Cropping background image when rendering region

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, texture-baking, render-layers

I have this scene with a hand and a knife and I want to get an animation of blood sorta dripping (spraying) from it, but because of SSS I use in palm material it takes forever to render (over 4 minutes!), so I decided to render this image and use it as a background to free calculating space.

[image: subsurface takes it forever to render!]

I managed to shorten the time of frame render to 25 secs by using the pre-rendered image of a hand and knife as background image and translucent render of current frame mixed by the alpha mixer.

[image: Nodles]

It looked great and it worked just fine. But then I thought I can render only the region where the animation of blood flushing will be (marked it with red rectangle), so I turned on *Render Region*

[image: Knife]

Cycles cropped the background image in final render, though in the compositing viewer I see it how I thought it would look: whole and not cropped like this!

Could you kindly explain me what the heck am I doing wrong, is it a bug?

Comment: Are you trying to disable the cropping region ? The shortcut is CTRL + ALT + B

Comment: No, i am trying to render a region and then merge this region with the background image using alpha over.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
I decided to render only one layer and only "render region" without checking "crop the render region" (output menu -> dimensions) to png so the output is transparent.

After rendering separate frames of animation I put it together with alpha over node in the compositor. I wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: @RayMairlot, fair enough, thanks for the heads up. It was actually in the original post so I didn't know if I could remove it or not. Now I know ! cheers

Comment: @Gorgious Ah that's my mistake, I didn't see that it was in the original.

Answer (score 0):

Plug the *Alpha* socket of foreground as *Factor* ...

[image]

... but you are right, it is weird.
When rendered as *Render Region* enabled, it does what it say. Than when composite it should be up to render setup, so I would expect compositor's view is correct (and render result wrong keeping just region area composed.

I can understand someone could find it useful to keep render region also after composite, but that should be achieved by another way ... also it seems to be a bug if plugging Alpha as Factor solves this issue.

Probably good to try bug tracker, what devs say ...